# How to make a SwiftUI conditional modifier works with different result types?

Tags: swift, swiftui

This code...

```
Text("Hello, world!")
    .background(.regularMaterial, in: condition ? RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6) : Circle())
```

...causes this issue:

> Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'RoundedRectangle' and 'Circle'

Is there a way to solve it without using the `if/else` syntax?

Comment: Have you tried casting? `condition ? (RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6) as InsettableShape) : (Circle() as InsettableShape)`

Comment: This causes another issue: `Protocol 'InsettableShape' as a type cannot conform to the protocol itself`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or if you want to definitely stick with ternary:

```
   Text("Hello, world!")
        .padding()
        .background(
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                    .fill(.regularMaterial)
                    .opacity(condition ? 1 :0)
                Circle()
                    .fill(.regularMaterial)
                    .opacity(condition ? 0 :1)
            }
        )
```