# SwiftUI - Use either a Color or LinearGradient in the .foregroundStyle modifier

Tags: swiftui

I have the following code:

```
@State var type: String = "color"
@State var color: Color = Color(.black)
@State var gradient: LinearGradient = LinearGradient(colors: [.orange, .red],
                                                         startPoint: .top,
                                                         endPoint: .center)


Text("Hello World!").foregroundStyle(type == "color" ? color : gradient)
```

It complains that color and gradient aren't the same type. However, there is no conditional logic for modifiers. So, how can I achieve the desired outcome?

Note: I have around 14 other modifiers, so a wrapping if else won't work as some other modifiers have the same issue, so there will be too many if else combinations.

Comment: Ternary operator only works with same kind of views. You can put it inside an if-else or change Color with LinearGradient with black colors.

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71217008/how-to-make-a-swiftui-conditional-modifier-works-with-different-result-types

Answer (score 0):

`.foregroundStyle` accepts a  parameter of type `ShapeStyle`. So, you must create your own `ShapeStyle` implementation. However, the `ShapeStyle` protocol is hidden by Apple, along with most of SwiftUI, so it's tricky (and potentially problematic) to try to implement your own `ShapeStyle`.

With that being said, you can create your own `ShapeStyle`, and thus what you're trying to accomplish, by following the steps [here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/Answers/CustomShapeStyle.md). (credit to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72049777/how-can-i-conform-to-shapestyle-protocol-in-swiftui) answer). Just throw your different cases in your `ShapeStyle` object and set the style accordingly.

You should honestly use if/else statements, and if you're worried about readability just throw it into a function.